# CodeIgniter local htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I created a small site usign CI and theme (only the content change). In the first run, it works perfectly but when I click another link the view change but the url doesn't. this is my .htaccess content 
`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`

and in my config:

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/';
$config['index_page'] = '';`

this is the content of my routes:

`$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['test'] = 'welcome/test';`

and here is my link: `<a href="test">Contact</a>`

is anyone can help me please? Thanks in advance
(Sorry for my bad english :) )

Comment: can you check this - $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Comment: Can you please check with this - Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: still the same result, the view changes but not the url

Comment: can you check with this - $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Comment: I get an 500 status code

Comment: this is my controller's content:  
public function index()
 {
  $data = array('title' => 'Home');
  $this->load->theme('default');
  $this->load->view('index', $data);
 }
 
 public function test()
 {
  $data = array('title' => 'Test');
  $this->load->theme('default');
  $this->load->view('test', $data);
 }

Comment: can you try  -- # Put your installation directory here:
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
#Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

Comment: also make -- $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Comment: the url works, but I get an 404 error

Comment: can you make -- $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: unfortunatily, I still get an 404 error

Comment: unfortunatily, I still get an 404 error

`RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/ 
# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#For reuests that are not actual files or directories, 
#Rewrite to index.php/URL 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: unfortunatily, I still get an 404 error

`RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/ 
# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#For reuests that are not actual files or directories, 
#Rewrite to index.php/URL 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]`

in my config: $config['base_url']= '';$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: it's working here. If you keep only -- RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/ # Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #For reuests that are not actual files or directories, #Rewrite to index.php/URL RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: I get "The requested URL /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/test was not found on this server." when I click my link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please look at the below and it's working at my localhost

```
config.php
=======================
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';


.httacces
=======================

#Initialize mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/site_folder/, use /site_folder/
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.1.4/

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


#For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
#Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: my view changes perfectly but not the url. It still show the base url in the browser

Comment: it works. the probleme is due to angularjs. when I remove the ng-app from my page, it works.